# Laravel 6.18 merge 2 list by its ids

Tags: laravel

I need to merge 2 list by its ids and get a result that would be added column on result
I'm just adding this text cuz stackoverflow tells me to add more text

```
    array1 = [
 {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "paul1",
},
{
  id: 2,
  firstName: "paul2",
},
{
  id: 3,
  firstName: "paul3",
}]

    array2 = [
 {
  id: 1,
  lastName: "jackson1"
},
{
  id: 3,
  lastName: "jackson3"
}]
```

and merge result would be

```
result = [
 {
  id: 1,
  firstName: "paul1",
  lastName: "jackson1"
},
{
  id: 2,
  firstName: "paul2",
},
{
  id: 3,
  firstName: "paul3",
  lastName: "jackson3"
}]
```

Comment: you can use `array_replace_recursive` with `array_combine`

Comment: Can you share from where you get those array? It may be easier to use relations in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment "you can use `array_replace_recursive` with `array_combine`"
Suppose you have these two arrays:

```
$array1 = array([
            'id'=>1,
            "firstName"=> "paul1",
        ], [
            'id'=>3,
            "firstName"=> "paul `has no last name`3",
        ], [
            'id'=>2,
            "firstName"=> "paul2",
        ],);

$array2 = array([
            'id'=>1,
            "lastName"=> "jackson1",
        ], [
            'id'=>2,
            "lastName"=> "jackson2",
        ], [
            'id'=>5,
            "lastName"=> "jackson `has no first name`5",
        ],);
```

so you can just merge them by id like this :

```
$marged = array_replace_recursive(
            array_combine(array_column($array1, "id"), $array1),
            array_combine(array_column($array2, "id"), $array2)
            )
```

**NOTE: You can change the "id" with the key you want**

so the OUTPUT should be like this:

```
array:4 [▼
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "firstName" => "paul1"
    "lastName" => "jackson1"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "firstName" => "has no last name3"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "firstName" => "paul2"
    "lastName" => "jackson2"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "lastName" => "jackson5"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $array1;
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $match = collect($array2)->firstWhere('id', $value['id']);
    $result[$key]['lastName'] = $match ? $match['lastName'] : '';
}
```